# Text.getBytes() returns unexpected results

Tags: java, serialization, unicode, encoding, hadoop

I'm getting some behavior from the Text constructors that don't really make any sense.  Basically, if I construct a Text object from a String, it is not equal to another Text object that I constructed from bytes, even though getBytes() returns the same value for both objects.

So we get weird stuff like this :

```
//This succeeds
assertEquals(new Text("ACTACGACCA_0"), new Text("ACTACGACCA_0")); 
//This succeeds
assertEquals((new Text("ACTACGACCA_0")).getBytes(), (new Text("ACTACGACCA_0")).getBytes()); 
//This fails.  Why?
assertEquals(new Text((new Text("ACTACGACCA_0")).getBytes()), new Text("ACTACGACCA_0"));
```

This manifests when I'm trying to access a hashmap.  Here, I'm trying to do a lookup based on a value returned by org.apache.hadoop.hbase.KeyValue.getRow() :

```
//This succeeds
assertEquals((new Text("ACTACGACCA_0")).getBytes(), keyValue.getRow()); 
//This returns a value
hashMap.get(new Text("ACTACGACCA_0"));  
//This returns null.  Why?
hashMap.get(new Text(keyValue.getRow()));
```

So what's going on here, and how do I deal with it?  Does this have something to do with encoding?

### UPDATE : PROBLEM SOLVED

Thanks to Chris for pointing me in the right direction with this.  So, a little background : the keyValue object is captured (using a Mockito ArgumentCaptor) from a call to htable.put().  Basically, I had this chunk of code :

```
byte[] keyBytes = matchRow.getKey().getBytes();
RowLock rowLock = hTable.lockRow(keyBytes);                         

Get get = new Get(keyBytes, rowLock);               
SetWritable<Text> toWrite = new SetWritable<Text>(Text.class);
toWrite.getValues().addAll(matchRow.getMatches(hTable, get));

Put put = new Put(keyBytes, rowLock);
put.add(Bytes.toBytes(MatchesByHaplotype.MATCHING_COLUMN_FAMILY), Bytes.toBytes(MatchesByHaplotype.UID_QUALIFIER), 
        SERIALIZATION_HELPER.serialize(toWrite));               
hTable.put(put);
```

where matchRow.getKey() returns a text object.  You see the problem here?  I was adding all the bytes, **including the invalid ones.**  So I created a nice helper function that does this :

```
public byte[] getValidBytes(Text text) {
    return Arrays.copyOf(text.getBytes(), text.getLength());
}
```

And changed the first line of that block to this :

```
byte[] keyBytes = SERIALIZATION_HELPER.getValidBytes(matchRow.getKey());
```

Problem solved!  In retrospect : wow, what a nasty bug!  I think what it comes down to is that the behavior of Text.getBytes() is very n00b-unfriendly.  Not only does it return something that you may not expect (non-valid bytes), the Text object doesn't have a function to return only the valid bytes!  You would think this would be a common use-case.  Maybe they'll add this in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the same reason that the following fails:

```
Assert.assertEquals((new Text("ACTACGACCA_0")).getLength(), (new Text("ACTACGACCA_0")).getBytes().length);
```

`getBytes()` returns the backing byte array, but according to the API, the bytes are only valid upto `Text.getLength();`

- [Text.getBytes()](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/Text.html#getBytes%28%29)

Yes, this does have to do with encoding - the CharsetEncoder.encode method uses a ByteBuffer whose size is initially allocated to 12 * 1.1 bytes (13) in length, but the actual valid number of bytes is still only 12 (as you are using solely ASCII characters).

Comment: Wow!  Thanks for the insight!  So how do people normally deal with this?  Do I need to truncate the array of bytes[] every time I make a call to Text.getBytes()?  What a pain!  I wonder why they'd design it that way.

Comment: Text is a mutable construct, allowing for object re-use and big gains in efficiency. As for your problem, if keyValue implements the hashCode() method (not natively), then you can just use that as your HashMap key type, otherwise create a wrapper class that does correctly implement hashCode (see WritableComparator.hashBytes())

Comment: Well, I'm not sure I can do that -- the hashMap needs to be general-purpose, as it's used for other things.  But thanks for the help! It would have taken me a million years to find that on my own.  I think I've got it from here, although other ideas are welcome.

Comment: So wait -- I'm actually still a little confused.  It sounds like Text.equals() is kinda broken.  Since Text(keyValue.getRow()) is "ACTACGACCA_0", how come this line returns false :
(new Text(keyValue.getRow())).equals(new Text("ACTACGACCA_0"))

Comment: If the bytes of keyValue.getRow() are 12 bytes in length, and match the "ACTACGACCA_0".getBytes(), then this is expected as the valid bytes match

Comment: Okay, so that would explain why assertEquals((new Text("ACTACGACCA_0")).getBytes(), keyValue.getRow()) succeeds.  But how come the Text.equals() returns false when I execute (new Text(keyValue.getRow())).equals(new Text("ACTACGACCA_0"))? keyValue.getRow().length and keyValue.getRowlength() both return the same number, so keyValue.getRow() should only be returning valid bytes, right?

Comment: Okay, problem solved.  See update.  Major thanks to Chris for helping me with this!